# VB regex extract strings between brackets and store in array

Tags: regex, vb.net, extract

I have raw data in the format:

> <&70><+><&10><+>.002<&70><+>B<&70><+>A<+><&90>

I would like to use VB to extract the contexts between `<` and `>` and store them in an array, such as `{&70,+,&10,+, ... }`

Then I would like to do the same for the items NOT between the brackets, also storing in an array like `{.002, B, A}`

Does anyone know how I can do this using regex?

Comment: Here's a doc on regex's in VB, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/818802 and a regex that should pull the data you need, `<.+?>`. I don't know regex syntax in VB so can't offer much more right now.

Comment: @chris85 your link is about VB6 not VB.Net. here is the [Regex class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation

Answer (score 1):

Storing in an array could be difficult upfront because you don't know which size they will be ; but you can use `List(Of String)` instead (and as final step call the `ToArray extension method` on them if you really want)

Using the regex given by [sln](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557597/sln) (why is way better than what I was doing) you need to loop through all the matches in your data using [Regex.Matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or it's [instance counterpart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want to create [and compile] the regex upfront)
And then if the current match has the indicated group (1 or 2 as shown in sln's regex explanation) add it to the corresponding list.

```
Dim rawData As String = "<&70><+><&10><+>.002<&70><+>B<&70><+>A<+><&90>"

Dim betweenBrackets As New List(Of String)
Dim outsideBrackets As New List(Of String)

For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(rawData, "<([^>]*)>|((?:(?!<[^>]*>)[\S\s])+)")
    If m.Groups(1).Success Then betweenBrackets.Add(m.Groups(1).Value)
    If m.Groups(2).Success Then outsideBrackets.Add(m.Groups(2).Value)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you @Sehnsucht! How can I then access the elements of the lists in VB? When I try to access an item using Return betweenBrackets.Item(0) I get an error.

Comment: @DanielWang yeah that's my fault I swapped the arguments of Regex.Matches by mistake so the code ran fine but obviously there was no match at all (hence no item in the list) ; I edit my answer to correct. As a side note you can access directly items inside a list using the indexer (like an array) `betweenBrackets(0)` [it's exactly the same thing as using `Item(0)`]

Comment: Thanks @Sehnsucht! When I try outputting outsideBrackets(0) I get "+>" instead of ".002". Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: @DanielWang not really; when i execute the code I don't have what you describe but the expected result

Answer (score 0):

I would do both operations at the same time in a global search.
If group 1 matched, push into bracket array,
if group 2 matched, push into non-bracket array.

```
 # <([^>]*)>|((?:(?!<[^>]*>)[\S\s])+)

   < 
   ( [^>]* )                     # (1)
   >
|  
   (                             # (2 start)
        (?:
             (?! < [^>]* > )
             [\S\s] 
        )+
   )                             # (2 end)
```

Comment: Could you explain how exactly this works and how I can incorporate it into VB?